# Open System Interconnection Reference Model 7 layer example?

Tags: network-protocols

A long time ago I tried to study the Open System Interconnection Reference Model 7 layer network protocol standard and gave up after I couldn't find any actual examples of an application which used all 7 layers.  Are there any examples now of applications which use and implement all 7 layers?  Or are the highest few layers a product of the fevered imagination of a standards committee?  Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is one I know of: the NMS (Network Management System) protocols for managing SONET (Synchronous Optical NETwork) network elements. The CMISE protocol stack (if I recall correctly) is built on top of the recommended OSI model.  You can get the relevant links to **some** documentation (I remember we had to buy those recommendations documents for mucho $$$) by searching for TelCordia GR-253.

Bear in mind that the OSI model is just what it is: a model.  The real networks and protocols out there do not follow the OSI model that closely, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

The International Organization for Standardization (ISO) developed the OSI model and also a suite of protocols which follow that model very closely.

Here is an example of a protocol stack using ISO protocols (this is the stack I used to work on 15 years ago when I was working on the management network for SONET telco equipment):

```
Layer 7 (Application): 
  ISO 8571: File Transfer Access and Management (FTAM)
  ISO 9596: Common Management Information Protocol (CMIP)

Layer 6 (Presentation): 
  ISO 8823: Presentation Layer Protocol

Layer 5 (Session):
  ISO 8327: Connection-oriented Session Protocol

Layer 4 (Transport):
  ISO 8073: Protocol for providing the connection-mode transport service  

Layer 3 (Network):
 ISO 8473: Protocol for providing the connectionless-mode network service

Layer 2 (Datalink):
  ISO 8802-2: Local and metropolitan area networks -- Specific requirements -- Part 2: Logical link control   

Layer 1:
  SONET DCC
```

These ISO/IEC protocols were somewhat widely used in the 80's and 90's, but these days they are only used in a few niche applications and the ISO/IEC protocols have mostly been replaced by the TCP/IP protocol stack which uses the ISO model only loosely.